# Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on a non-object in /***/***/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 600

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework, mysqli

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on a non-object in /***/***/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 600
```

I'm getting this issue while i move magento website from localhost to live server. I have followed all steps to move. It is working great on local but having mentioned issue on live server. i have checked all files and folder permissions are 755, 644.

After search couples of day nothing solution found. please help me to fix this. 
Magento ver. is 1.9.0.1,
php ver. 5.4

function on line 600 in config.php is

```
public function extend(Varien_Simplexml_Config $config, $overwrite=true)
{
    $this->getNode()->extend($config->getNode(), $overwrite);
    return $this;
}
```

i would really appreciate your support.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the magneto **can't read your xml files**. So check file permission again for xml files and check your xml files under `app/etc` folder and every custom modules under `app/code/local/` may be some xml files are corrupted (miss formed).

Comment: i have upload fresh data from local and also check all file permission but still same issue.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Some times the file permission will be changed in server. I faced many times ( some kind of poor hosting providers)

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same error as above when installing the SoftProdigy "Enhanced Order Delivery Date" extension.

This specific instance was easily reslved to heading to app/etc and renaming the folder from Softprodigy_Deliverydate.xml to Softprodigy_Deliverydate.

Both front and back office available again following the renaming.

I hope this helps!